# Is there a downside to using setter functions for variables that are never read outside a class?

Tags: ios, swift, interface, setter

Suppose my (immensely oversimplified) application code looks like this:

```
// Foo.swift
protocol FooDelegate: class {
    func didBar(on foo: Foo)
}

class Foo {
    weak var delegate: FooDelegate?
}

private extension Foo {
    func _bar() {
        self.delegate?.didBar(on: self)
    }
}
```

```
// Baz.swift

class Baz: FooDelegate {
    init() {
        let foo: Foo = Foo()
        foo.delegate = self
        self._foo = foo
    }

    private var _foo: Foo

    func didBar(on foo: Foo) {
        print("Bazinga!")
    }
}
```

Since nothing outside Foo.swift ever reads the `.delegate` of any Foo instance, I could modify Foo like this:

```
// Foo.swift
protocol FooDelegate: class {
    func didBar(on foo: Foo)
}

extension Foo {
    func setDelegate(_ delegate: FooDelegate?) {
        self._delegate = delegate
    }
}

class Foo {
    private weak var _delegate: FooDelegate?
}

private extension Foo {
    func _bar() {
        self._delegate?.didBar(on: self)
    }
}
```

I can think of the following problems:

- it's a bit more code to write (actually, it's a bit less compared to how I would normally write it, see below)
- if I were to subclass the type and wanted to use the delegate inside the subclass' implementation, I would have to either implement the parts of the subclass that need to use the delegate inside Foo.swift or make the delegate variable internally accessible again

Are there any other possible downsides to this?

---

If the code was located in a framework instead of an application, I would definitely expose the variable so it's possible to use it in a subclass of the type. 
In my application code, I would like to only make it read-accessible if it's actually necessary, which, in a 20000 loc application I'm working on, was never.

---

How I would normally write it:

```
// Foo.swift
protocol FooDelegate: class {
    func didBar(on foo: Foo)
}

extension Foo {
    var delegate: FooDelegate? {
        get { return self._delegate }
        set { self._delegate = newValue }
    }
}

class Foo {
    private weak var _delegate: FooDelegate?
}

private extension Foo {
    func _bar() {
        self.delegate?.didBar(on: self)
    }
}
```

I do this because imho it makes it easier to gather a quick overview over the internal/public interface of a type compared to having privately and internally accessible variables all in the class declaration. In this case it's only one variable but imagine you have a type that has 10 internally accessible variables, another 5 variables that are only privately accessible, some of these vars are weak, some lazy, maybe there's also a few static variables, a few overrides (which need to be declared in the class declaration as well) and some initialisers.

Comment: In my opinion the answer to this question is "Whatever suits you the best" since it is very much about personal opinion and taste

Comment: I share that opinion, just want to be sure I'm not missing something obvious that will bite me in my behind later if I were to change my style regarding this. :)